# <b>Warning</b>: Undefined variable $row in / Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un botón que es para editar datos en un Form. Pero cuando entro al formulario para editar los datos, me tira esos mensajes de error en las casillas de **'producto'** y **'marca'**. Este es el **código** del formulario editar:

Este es el **código** donde incluyo el servidor que conecta con la base de datos y el footer donde se encuentran los links de bootstrap:

```
    <?php include('server.php');
include('includes/footer.php');

if(isset($_GET['idProducto']))
{
    $idProducto = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['idProducto']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE idProducto='$idProducto' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $idProducto = $row['idProducto'];
        $producto = $row['producto'];
        $categoria = $row['categoria'];
        $marca = $row['marca'];
        $cantidadAct = $row['cantidadAct'];
        $precio = $row['precio'];
    }
}
?>
```

Y este es el formulario donde debería traer los datos actuales **(lo cual no lo hace)** para poder actualizarlos:

```
<div class="container pt-2">
    <form method="POST" class="agg-product mb-1" action="botonesProd.php" >
      <?php include('errors.php'); ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="idProducto" value="<?= $productos['idProducto']; ?>">

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Producto</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="producto" id="producto"         placeholder="Ingresar producto" value="<?php echo $row['producto'];?>">
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Categoria</label>
        <select name="categoria" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" value="    <?php echo $row['categoria'];?>">
          <option selected>Seleccionar categoria</option>
          <option value="Productos escolares">Productos escolares</option>
          <option value="Libreria">Libreria</option>
          <option value="Jugueteria">Juegueteria</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Marca</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="marca" name="marca" placeholder="Ingresar marca" value="<?php echo $row['marca'];?>">
      </div>


      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Cantidad Act.</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cantidadAct" name="cantidadAct" placeholder="Ingresar cantidad" value="<?php echo $row['cantidadAct'];?>">
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Precio</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="precio" placeholder="Ingresar precio" value="<?php echo $row['precio'];?>">
      </div>

      <!-- Botones de modal -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal" name="btn-cerrar">Cerrar</button>
        <input type="submit" name="actualizarProd" class="btn btn-primary" value="Actualizar">
      </div>
    </form>
   </div>
```

**Adjunto imagen** de como se muestran los mensajes de error:
[image: Mensajes de error]

Comment: Hola! Puedes probar haciendo un var_dump a tu variable $query para ver cómo te tira la consulta y luego ir a probarla en tu gestor de bd.

Comment: El problema aparece en las líneas `193` y `208` del archivo  `editarProd.php`. Me parece que no estás mostrando ese código, sino otro. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el código en cuestión.

Comment: El error puede radicar en que tu consulta es errónea, o estas haciendo el **include** mal, por eso no reconoce la variable $row.